# large amount of inserts per seconds causing massive CPU load

Tags: php, mysql, performance, nosql

I have a PHP script that in every run, inserts a new row to a Mysql db (with a relative small amount of data..)
I have more than 20 requests per second, and this is causing my CPU to scream for help..

I'm using the sql `INSERT DELAYED` method with a MyISAM engine (although I just notice that `INSERT DELAYED` is not working with MyISAM).

My main concern is my CPU load and I started to look for ways to store this data with more CPU friendly solutions.

My first idea was to write this data to an hourly log files and once an hour to retrieve the data from the logs and insert it to the DB at once.

Maybe a better idea is to use NoSQL DB instead of log files and then once an hour to insert the data from the NoSQL to the Mysql..

I didn't test yet any of these ideas, so I don't really know if this will manage to decrease my CPU load or not. I wanted to ask if someone can help me find the right solution that will have the lowest affect over my CPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok guys, I manage to lower the CPU load dramatically with APC-cache

I'm doing it like so:

storing the data in memory with APC-cache, with TTL of 70 seconds:

```
apc_store('prfx_SOME_UNIQUE_STRING', $data, 70);
```

once a minute I'm looping over all the records in the cache:

```
$apc_list=apc_cache_info('user');

foreach($apc_list['cache_list'] as $apc){
    if((substr($apc['info'],0,5)=='prfx_') && ($val=apc_fetch($apc['info']))){
        $values[]=$val;
        apc_delete($apc['info']);
    }
}
```

inserting the `$values` to the DB

and the CPU continues to smile..

enjoy

Answer (score 4):

I recently had a very similar problem and my solution was to simply batch the requests.  This sped things up about 50 times because of the reduced overhead of mysql connections and also the greatly decreased amount of reindexing.  Storing them to a file then doing one larger (100-300 individual inserts) statement at once probably is a good idea.  To speed things up even more turn off indexing for the duration of the insert with

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DISABLE KEYS
insert statement
ALTER TABLE tablename ENABLE KEYS
```

doing the batch insert will reduce the number of instances of the php script running, it will reduce the number of currently open mysql handles (large improvement) and it will decrease the amount of indexing.

Comment: That might not be a good idea if some other process is writing to the database concurrently.

Comment: And as to "reduced overhead of mysql connections" -- you weren't really opening a new connection for each insert, I hope?

Answer (score 0):

I would insert a sleep(1); function at the top of your PHP script, before every insert at the top of your loop where 1 = 1 second. This only allows the loop to cycle once per second.

This way it will regulate a bit just how much load the CPU is getting, this would be ideal assuming your only writing a small number of records in each run.

You can read more about the sleep function here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The script inserts only 1 record in every run,
The problem is that I have 20 new users who running this script every second..

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without profiling both methods, if you write to a log file first you could end up just making it worse as your turning your operation count from N to N*2.  You gain a slight edge by writing it all to a file and doing a batch insert but bear in mind that as the log file fills up it's load/write time increases.

To reduce database load, look at using mem cache for database reads if your not already.

All in all though your probably best of just trying both and seeing what's faster.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying INSERT DELAYED, I assume you don't need up to the second data. If you want to stick with MySQL, you can try using replication and the BLACKHOLE table type. By declaring a table as type BLACKHOLE on one server, then replicating it to a MyISAM or other table type on another server, you can smooth out CPU and io spikes. BLACKHOLE is really just a replication log file, so "inserts" into it are very fast and light on the system.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is your table size or your server capabilities but I guess you need to make a lot of inserts per single table. In such a situation I would recommend checking for the construction of vertical partitions that will reduce the physical size of each partition and significantly reduce the insertion time to the table.